# Sumar subgrupos en MySQL cuando una columna tenga cierto valor

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
| start_date               | end_date             |     sales    | is_finished |
|:------------------------:|---------------------:|:------------:|:------------:
| 2017-03-24 09:11:00      |  2017-03-24 09:11:00 |     30       |       1
| 2017-03-24 08:30:00      |  2017-03-24 08:30:00 |     50       |       1
| 2017-03-24 08:14:00      |  2017-03-24 08:14:00 |     100      |       1
| 2017-03-24 07:30:00      |  2017-03-24 07:45:00 |     200      |       0 
| 2017-03-24 07:00:00      |  2017-03-24 07:00:00 |     150      |       1 
| 2017-03-24 06:40:00      |  2017-03-24 06:50:00 |     450      |       0
```

Necesito agrupar por `start_date` y `end_date` e ir sumando el valor de la columna `sales`. Ahora bien, deben ser agrupados de igual forma cada vez que la columna `is_finished` tenga un uno.

Esto es, que las columnas que tengan un cero se irán sumando y cuando un uno aparezca debe agruparse como un conjunto.

Necesito el siguiente resultado:

```
| start_date               | end_date             |   SUM(sales) |
|:------------------------:|---------------------:|:------------:|
| 2017-03-24 09:11:00      |  2017-03-24 09:11:00 |     30       |
| 2017-03-24 08:30:00      |  2017-03-24 08:30:00 |     50       |
| 2017-03-24 07:30:00      |  2017-03-24 08:14:00 |     300      |
| 2017-03-24 06:40:00      |  2017-03-24 07:00:00 |     600      |
```

Por ahora tengo un *query* pero el problema es que cuando hay 2 o más filas que tengan el valor 1 en la columna `is_finished` los toma como un grupo.

El *query* es:

```
SELECT SUM(sales) , MIN(start_date) , MAX(end_date) 
FROM sales 
GROUP BY 
start_date > (SELECT start_date FROM sales WHERE is_finished = 1  ORDER BY end_date ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1 ),
 end_date <= (SELECT end_date FROM sales WHERE is_finished = 1  ORDER BY end_date ASC LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY end_date DESC
```

Usando el *query* de arriba me acerco a lo que espero, pero tiene el problema mencionado.

Comment: Estamos viendo la tabla ordenada en forma cronológicamente descendente? Porque tu descripción y el resultado esperado se contradicen. Qué pasa si dos o más intervalos se superponen?

Answer (score 0):

Dejando mi pregunta de lado. Supongamos que la tabla es tal como la describiste y vas a listar las ventas en orden cronológicamente descendente.

```
create table ventas as 
select '2017-03-24 06:40:00' as start_date, '2017-03-24 06:50:00' as end_date, 450 as sales, 0 as is_finished
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-03-24 07:00:00','2017-03-24 07:00:00', 150, 1
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-03-24 07:30:00','2017-03-24 07:45:00', 200, 0
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-03-24 08:14:00','2017-03-24 08:14:00', 100, 1
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-03-24 08:30:00','2017-03-24 08:30:00', 50 , 1
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-03-24 09:11:00','2017-03-24 09:11:00', 30 , 1;

SELECT * from VENTAS ORDER BY start_date DESC
```

Eso se ve como en tu pregunta original:

```
| start_date               | end_date             |     sales    | is_finished |
|:------------------------:|---------------------:|:------------:|:------------:
| 2017-03-24 09:11:00      |  2017-03-24 09:11:00 |     30       |       1
| 2017-03-24 08:30:00      |  2017-03-24 08:30:00 |     50       |       1
| 2017-03-24 08:14:00      |  2017-03-24 08:14:00 |     100      |       1
| 2017-03-24 07:30:00      |  2017-03-24 07:45:00 |     200      |       0 
| 2017-03-24 07:00:00      |  2017-03-24 07:00:00 |     150      |       1 
| 2017-03-24 06:40:00      |  2017-03-24 06:50:00 |     450      |       0
```

Lo que se hace en MySQL es ayudarse de una variable. Esa variable se incrementa cuando `is_finished` es 1 y se mantiene igual cuando `is_finished` es 0. Esto significa: si es 1 es un nuevo lote. Si es cero, pertenece al lote de la fila anterior

```
   SELECT ventas.*,
          @thislote:=IF(is_finished=0,@thislote,@thislote+1) lote
   FROM ventas, (SELECT @thislote:=0) lote
   ORDER BY start_date DESC
```

Esto arroja

```
| start_date               | end_date             |   sales  | is_finished | lote |
|:------------------------:|---------------------:|:--------:|:------------:------|
| 2017-03-24 09:11:00      |  2017-03-24 09:11:00 |   30     |       1     | 1    |
| 2017-03-24 08:30:00      |  2017-03-24 08:30:00 |   50     |       1     | 2    | 
| 2017-03-24 08:14:00      |  2017-03-24 08:14:00 |   100    |       1     | 3    |
| 2017-03-24 07:30:00      |  2017-03-24 07:45:00 |   200    |       0     | 3    |
| 2017-03-24 07:00:00      |  2017-03-24 07:00:00 |   150    |       1     | 4    |
| 2017-03-24 06:40:00      |  2017-03-24 06:50:00 |   450    |       0     | 4    |
```

Si conviertes eso en una subquery, digamos `ventas_con_lote` entonces sólo tienes que hacer:

```
SELECT lote, SUM(sales) , MIN(start_date) , MAX(end_date) 
FROM ventas_con_lote 
GROUP BY lote
ORDER BY end_date DESC
```